# How to connect to SQL Server 2008 with asp net core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-core-2.0

i am learning a asp.net core 2, i am new at microsoft technology which is using Entity Framework and using Package Manager Console, what i do here is i am following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model

which is teach me about connection to database, but there is just connection to localdb, which is provided like this :

appsettings.json :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Movie-1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

but i want to connect to my SQL Server 2008 R2 which i installed it on my local server

here is my connection string look like :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MovieContext": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Movie-1;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

then i run a command "Update-Database" in Package Manager Console, then i got this error :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

but i can connect to my Sql server 2008 with SQL Studio management perfectly, which is i just put the servername : localhost and the default login. What do i miss there?

Comment: if you installed sql 2008 you likey should not be connecting to the `SQLEXPRESS` instance.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes i don't know about instance before, so i decided to delete the instance and it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that actually i don't need instance for the connection string, so here is how my appsettings.json looks like

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MovieContext": "Server=localhost;Database=Movie-1;User Id=root;Password=12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```